# Line-height and font-size on different browsers?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I'm trying to vertically align a number in a div.
Here's the code :

```
<div class="nb">2</div> 

display: inline-block;
height: 56px;
width: 56px;
background: transparent url("../img/stepnb.png") center center no-repeat;
line-height: 56px;
color: #255066;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,.75), -1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
font-size: 42px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-top: -25px;
```

[image]
note : the result is the same on IE9 to 11

As you can see, it's not vertically centered on different browsers.
Do you have an idea how I could achieve to align it on all major browsers without conditionnal comments or css hacks?

edit: the issue could come from the use of a css reset, I'll check that.

edit 2 : The alignment issue came from the "Myriad pro" font, which was assigned to a parent div.

Comment: You could do this with pseudo elements and position of the content: "2" absolute inside the circle

Comment: do you look for e.g. {vertical-align:text-top;} http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: srekoble ;  I guess I can't do it without adding html code? Actually there is only <div class="nb">2</div>

Thomas : I think it's not applicable in a div, unless it has a table-cell behavior (and then I wouldn't be able to center it with fixedwidth and auto margins)...

Comment: Show the HTML code, too, in the question (not just in a comment).

Comment: Did you try to use some [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Comment: Is that the complete CSS? I put it in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZS8s/1/), but in there the `2` is not centered. And there are differences in the vertical position, but not as big as the ones in your screenshot.

Comment: Vucko : Absolutely! I used the well known normalize.css. The issue may come from this! I'll check that. Thank you for pointing this possibility :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment issue came from the "Myriad pro" font, which was assigned to a parent div.

Thank you all for the help :)